# Copy item not keeping folder structure

Tags: powershell

I have a folder "C:\program", which has two sub-directories "C:\program\Excel" and "C:\program\scripts" and several other files.
When I run the following, all the files copy successfully apart from the files in the Excel directory, which seem to copy to the root of $Destination instead of a directory being created in $Destination called Excel

```
    $Path = 'C:\program\*'

    $Destination = 'C:\program\Previous Version\'

    $Files = Get-ChildItem $Path  

    foreach ($File in $Files){
     Copy-Item $File.FullName $Destination -Recurse -Container
    }
```

How do I get Copy-Item to copy the contents of the Excel folder to a new Excel folder in the root of $Destination?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you copy folder directly? `copy-item a-folder -Recurse destination-container`

Comment: The problem is that I need to do Get-ChildItem of the source folder, so that I have a count of the files to be copied, so that I can show a progress bar for the copy of the folder. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That stipulation should be part of the question as it is and important detail.